# Eclipse cannot resolve org.springframework.extensions.*

Tags: eclipse, ide

I should develope a java backed web script for alfresco but some libraries are missing on the classpath so most of the classes I like to use can not be resolved. **I can build the project** but Eclipse can not find the classes:

```
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptRequest;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptResponse;
```

Where can I download the jar to add it to the classpath? I already searched and googled but I cannot find a download :/

Comment: If the project can be built then the classes (and thus associated JAR) *are* found by the build process and *are* available locally. Then it's just a matter of making sure that Eclipse uses the same JARs/classpath entries.

Comment: Exactly ... but where are the JARs defined maven is using?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using maven ,add this to your pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.extensions.surf</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webscripts</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.extensions.surf</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webscripts-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M3</version>
      </dependency>
```